# java8 map how to add some element to a list value simply

Tags: java-8

I want to use `Map<String, List<String>>` to record something, e.g.
each city have how many users of some kind .

Now my code is

```
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    if(map.get("city_1")==null){
        map.put("city_1", new ArrayList<>());
    }
    map.get("city_1").add("aaa");
```

but I feel it's a little cumbersome, I want this effect

```
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.compute("city_1", (k,v)->v==null?new ArrayList<>():v.add("aaa"));
```

but it has compile error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to List<String>
```

So have any other manner could simplify it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-):

```
map.computeIfAbsent(work, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add("aaa");
```

Which stores a new list in the map if it does not already exist and returns the new or existing list.